# v-slot attribute recieving an object as value

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

So, before anything else, I know that the v-slot attribute receives an object as value, but written like this:

```
v-slot="slotProps"
```

But I stumbled over this piece of code:

```
v-slot="{ isHovering, props }"
```

Does this mean that I extract only these specific props from the slotProps object?

Comment: Yes, its called a destructuring assignment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment